# How to pas a final file name in UNIX shell scripts

Tags: shell, unix, arguments, filenames

```
inputLandingFullPath="$1"
inputDataFileName="$2"
inputLogFullPath="$3"
inputLoadingPath="$4"
Datalake_Key="$5"
Datalake_Id="$6"
InputScheme=${inputDataFileName:19:2}
echo "$InputScheme"
touch ${inputLoadingPath}\tmp-${InputScheme}.json
cp ${inputLoadingPath}\tmp-${InputScheme}.json ${inputLoadingPath}\${InputScheme}.json
```

Concatenation works fine when I specify a string with it, but does not when I specify without it.

This works Fine, produces file tmp-YS-json:

```
touch ${inputLoadingPath}\tmp-${InputScheme}.json
```

This does not work:

```
cp ${inputLoadingPath}\tmp-${InputScheme}.json ${inputLoadingPath}\${InputScheme}.json
```

The output is:

```
YS

tmp-YS.json.part5

${InputScheme}.json
```

And the desired output is:

```
YS.json
```

Arguments:

```
sh /Hadoop_SAN/TU_Prod/TMP/BB_Parse_JSON.sh '/Hadoop_SAN/TU_Prod/TMP/' 'tesco_qhv5_extract-YS-2018.08.15.json' '/Hadoop_SAN/TU_Prod/TMP/' '/Hadoop_SAN/TU_Prod/TMP/' 0 0
```

Comment: Are you confusing '\' with '/'?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using back slash use forward slash
Specify /
instead of \

${inputLoadingPath}/${InputScheme}.json